# AR.js Custom Markers

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am new to WebAR, but I have experience with building AR scenes with Unity3D and software such as Vuforia and 8thWall.

I have a question with the markers with AR.js. Why are they stuck with the thick black border? Is the software not able to just recognize a unique image like how Vuforia and Wikitude works? I apologize for how naive I may be when it comes to WebAR, however, I see this as an issue for the adoption rate of this technology if developers cannot use truly custom images and patterns. Is there a solution available that I may have missed somewhere? What happens if someone deletes/erases the big black border on the marker? Does it still work?

Thanks to anyone who can shed some light on this!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! As this is your first question, let me give you some tips: 
- Try to ask "how do I do something" instead of "why is this happening". For instance, you should ask "How can I remove the black borders on the markers?" instead of "Why are there black borders appearing?"
- To help others answer your question more effectively, you should provide a sample of the code you're using. This should be a small snippet of just the most important parts of your code.
Thanks and welcome to the community!

Answer (score 0):

[Ar.js](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/README.md#what-marker-based-means) uses [artoolkit](https://github.com/artoolkit/jsartoolkit5) and therefore is marker based. If you want to use it, there is not much you can do about it. Still You can have unique images inside the black box but not much else.

Worth mentioning, it is [possible to make the borders thinner](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/296), there's even a [branch](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/tree/setPattRatio/aframe) - work in progress worth looking into.

[Aframe-argon](https://github.com/argonjs/argon-aframe) tried integrating aframe and vuforia, but i'm not sure if it's up to date.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly! I am perfectly fine with marker based AR, as I believe it is extremely useful still and will be for a long time. I was just curious to see if there was an alternative to having the black border around the marker. What if I had a need for a circular marker, would that be impossible with AR.js?

Comment: Unfortunately not, with artoolkit backing AR.js it is limited to square markers. I'm, however working on a jpg based solution to overcome the square marker limitation. It is running fine on desktop and reasonable on mobile. If you are interested let me know.

Comment: Nothing open source at the moment.

Comment: @Thor_Bux could you throw in a comment once you upload something ? sounds awesome :)

Comment: I will. At the moment I'm looking for companies willing to invest in this technology and create a product out of it.

Comment: @Thor_Bux best of luck then !

Comment: @Thor_Bux I am definitely interested and agree with Piotr. Please update us when you upload something!

Comment: @Thor_Bux - curious if you ever made any headway on this. I was looking for a similar soluion myself & found this thread.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/354952125342920/posts/377735149731284?sfns=mo  https://www.facebook.com/354952125342920/posts/388361505335315?sfns=mo have a look at these links and tell me what you think. @genericandy

Comment: @Thor_Bux Great work! You going to be releasing it somewhere / somehow?

Comment: I’m working it into an ARStuido platform. If you are interested in an early preview, let me know.